# reuse code when binding to click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.went-cold-turkey').click(function() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
      var activity_day = this.rel;
      $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
            $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
          }
      });
      return false;
    });

    $('a.did-it-once').click(function() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
      var activity_day = this.rel;
      $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
            $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
          }
      });
      return false;
    });

  });
```

As you can see both ".click" calls are practically identical.  How can I share repetitive code in both to keep things DRY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

Bind with the function

```
function functionName(){}
$("selector1").click(functionName)
$("selector2").click(functionName)
```

Or bind with both selector at same search

```
$("selector1, selector2").click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass multiple selectors to jQuery's $ functin like so:

```
$('a.went-cold-turkey, a.did-it-once').click(function () {});
```

Alternatively, you could put your repetative code into a named function and pass that as the handler:

```
function handleEvent() {
    // Your code here
}

$('a.went-cold-turkey').click(handleEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: on 2nd though, just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.went-cold-turkey,a.did-it-once').click(function() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
      var activity_day = this.rel;
      $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
            $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
          }
      });
      return false;
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose those two A elements are in parent element with class "choices".

```
$('.choices a').click(function() {
  $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
  var activity_day = this.rel;
  $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be approximately what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var common = function(rel, href) {
    $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
    var activity_day = rel;
    $.ajax({
        url: thref,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
$('a.went-cold-turkey').click(function() {
    return common(this.rel, this.href);
});

$('a.did-it-once').click(function() {
    return common(this.rel, this.href);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code into a function and then just add the same click handler to both elements.

```
$(function(){

   function clickFn(){

     $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
     var activity_day = this.rel;
     $.ajax({
       url: this.href,
       type: "GET",
       cache: false,
       success: function (html) {
        $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
       }
     });
     return false;

   }

   $('a.went-cold-turkey, a.did-it-once').click( clickFn );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$('a.went-cold-turkey, a.did-it-once').click(function() {
  $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
  var activity_day = this.rel;
  $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As this:

```
function linkClick() {
  $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
  var activity_day = this.rel;
  $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
      }
  });
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.went-cold-turkey, a.did-it-once').click(linkClick);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both selectors in the function:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.went-cold-turkey, a.did-it-once').click(function() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
      var activity_day = this.rel;
      $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
            $('#'+activity_day).replaceWith(html);
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
          }
      });
      return false;
    });


  });
```